# How can I select the first element using XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a list of news items, sorted by dateCreated.  I have a preview box control where I only want to show the first item.  How can I do that using XSLT?

```
<xml>
    <news>
        <newsitem>
            <dateCreated>2009-09-09</dateCreated>
            <summary>Something great happened</sumamry>
        </newsitem>
        <newsitem>
            <dateCreated>2009-09-08</dateCreated>
            <summary>Something bad happened</sumamry>
        </newsitem>
        <newsitem>
            <dateCreated>2009-09-07</dateCreated>
            <summary>Something really bad happened</sumamry>
        </newsitem>
    </news>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you wish to output XHTML 1.1, here's one way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs">
<xsl:output mode="xhtml" version="1.1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
    encoding="utf-8" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" indent="no" 
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />

<xsl:template match="//newsItem[1]">
    <div><xsl:value-of select="dateCreated"/></div>
    <div><xsl:value-of select="summary"/></div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: The problem with [1] is that if I also need to process the nodes normally, the first node has been consumed.

So if all the newsitems need to be processed, but the first one must be processed specially (like output table headers), using this approach won't work.  I'm hoping to find that.

Comment: @tggagne Not sure what you mean by "consumed". If you need to do headers, maybe do that higher up the tree, i.e. `match="//news[newsitem]"`, then apply-templates from within that.

Comment: Is there a way to use a param value for this? I tried "//news[$show]" where $show is the number of the element I wanna show.

Comment: @janlindso That should work. What did you end up with?

Comment: It seems you cannot add a variable in a match. So I added it in the apply-templates instead. Like this: <xsl:apply-templates select="book/chapter[position() = $chapter]" /> It worked!

Answer (score 15):

```
//newsItem[1]
```

should do

Answer (score 12):

I had the same question and I think I found a better answer:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="newsItem[1]">
  <div><xsl:value-of select="dateCreated"/></div>
  <div><xsl:value-of select="summary"/></div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//newsItem[1]
```

Selects the first book `newsItem` element, but note that IE5 and later has implemented that `[0]` should be the first node, but according to the W3C standard it should be `[1]`!