# How can I match the first element in the document using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

this is a follow up for [How can I select the first element using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498819/how-can-i-select-the-first-element-using-xslt) .

```
<xml>
    <news>
        <newsitem>
            <dateCreated>2009-09-09</dateCreated>
            <summary>Something great happened</sumamry>
        </newsitem>
        <newsitem>
            <dateCreated>2009-09-08</dateCreated>
            <summary>Something bad happened</sumamry>
        </newsitem>
    </news>
    <news>
        <newsitem>
            <dateCreated>2009-09-07</dateCreated>
            <summary>Something really bad happened</sumamry>
        </newsitem>
    </news>
</xml>
```

How can I match against the first `newsitem` element in the document?  the `xsl:template match="//newsItem[1]"` match sujested in the other question will get the first child. `xsl:template match="(//newsItem)[1]"` is not valid.  The only other hints I've gotten involves doing some complicated/messy stuff with keys, it seems like there should be a better answer,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, I think you should use :

```
<xsl:template match="//news[1]/newsitem[1]"> to select the first item of all.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my real situation I cannot those assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple match pattern that will select the first element of name newsitem in the document. You can do it with a predicate:

```
match="newsitem[not(preceding::newsitem)]"
```

but the performance is likely to be horrible.

With XSLT 2.0 the best solution is to bind a global variable and test for it:

```
<xsl:variable name="first-newsitem" select="(//newsitem)[1]"/>

<xsl:template match="newsitem[. is $first-newsitem]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In XSLT 1.0 one can use this**:

```
newsitem[not(ancestor::newsitem or preceding::newsitem)]
```