# XSLT parsing a HTML table: need only top level tr not children

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm transforming a table in XML via XSLT to create tabs with cards under each, like an tab accordion with cards for each tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="messin-table.xsl"?>
<table class="messin-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Accordion Heading</th>
                <th>Name, Blurb and image</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading" colspan="3">Staff</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>head 1</p>
                    </td>
                    <td><p>body 1</p></td>
                    <td>blurb 1</td>
                    <td><p><img src="img/SBU-logo.png" /></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>head 2</p>
                    </td>
                    <td><p>body 2</p></td>
                    <td>blurb 2</td>
                    <td><p><img src="img/SBU-logo.png" /></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>head 6</p>
                    </td>
                    <td><p>body 9</p></td>
                    <td>blurb 9</td>
                    <td><p><img src="img/SBU-logo.png" /></p></td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading" colspan="3">Faculty</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>head 4</p>
                    </td>
                    <td><p>body 4</p></td>
                    <td>blurb 4</td>
                    <td><p><img src="img/SBU-logo.png" /></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>head 7</p>
                    </td>
                    <td><p>body 7</p></td>
                    <td>blurb 7</td>
                    <td><p><img src="img/SBU-logo.png" /></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>head 12</p>
                    </td>
                    <td><p>body 12</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><p><img src="img/SBU-logo.png" /></p></td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading" colspan="3">Support</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>head 19</p>
                    </td>
                    <td><p>body 19</p></td>
                    <td>blurb 19</td>
                    <td><p><img src="img/SBU-logo.png" /></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>head 22</p>
                        
                        
                    </td>
                    <td><p>body 22</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><p><img src="img/SBU-logo.png" /></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>head 36</p>
                        
                        
                    </td>
                    <td><p>body 36</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><p><img src="img/SBU-logo.png" /></p></td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have nested loops in my XSL. I need the first loop to only loop the top level tr/td class='heading' to make tabs, and then loop through the inner trs to create the content (cards) under the tabs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:ou="http://omniupdate.com/XSL/Variables"
                xmlns:fn="http://omniupdate.com/XSL/Functions"
                xmlns:ouc="http://omniupdate.com/XSL/Variables"
                xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"  
                xmlns:dm="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"
                xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata"
                extension-element-prefixes="date str"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs ou fn ouc">
<section id="wrapper">
                     <div class="content"><!-- Tab links -->
                        <div class="tabs">
                        <xsl:for-each select="tbody/tr">
                        <xsl:variable name="datacountry" select="td[@class='heading']" />
                        <button class='tablinks' data-country='{$datacountry}'  aria-controls='{$datacountry}'>
                              <p data-title="{$datacountry}"><xsl:value-of select="td[1]"/></p></button> 
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </div>


                    <div class="wrapper_tabcontent">
                    <xsl:for-each select="tbody/tr">
                    <xsl:variable name="country" select="td[@class='heading']" />
                           <div id="{$country}" class="tabcontent" role="tabpanel">
                              <div class="wrap">
                                <xsl:for-each select="tr">

                                <xsl:variable name="cardname" select="./td[1]" />
                                <xsl:variable name="cardheader" select="./td[2]" />
                                <xsl:variable name="cardbody" select="./td[3]" />
                                <xsl:variable name="cardimg" select="./td[4]/p/img" />
                                 <div class="item" style="transition-delay: 75ms;">
                                    <article class="card" tabindex="0">
                                       <a href="#" data-bio="{$cardheader}'s bio">
                                       <div><xsl:copy-of select="$cardimg"/></div>
                                       <header>
                                          <p><xsl:value-of select="$cardname"/></p> 
                                          <p><xsl:value-of select="$cardheader"/></p>
                                       </header>
                                       <div class="byline">
                                          <p class="hide caption">
                                             <xsl:value-of select="$cardbody"/>
                                             </p>
                                       </div>
                                       </a>
                                    </article>
                                 </div>
                                 </xsl:for-each>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           </xsl:for-each>
                        </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </section>
                                           <div class="modals" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modalTitle">
   <span class="close">x</span>
 </div>
                        <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
                        <script src="js/tabbed-accordion-people.js"></script>
                        </body>
                        </html>
                   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should look like this:

[image]

What this is doing instead is ALL trs are being created as tabs. Is there a way to select just the trs right under the tbody? And then, loop through the inner trs to create the content?

The irony is when I test on my local machine this works (I know you all know that pain!).

Thank you!!!

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Yitzak, I've edited the question, hoping that what you've requested is there.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me from quick inspection, and the fact that it's working in one particular environment suggests that we're looking for something outside the code itself as the cause of the problem. You haven't said much about the two different ways of running the code, other than the fact that one of them is "on your local machine". I suspect we need to know more.

Comment: The XSLT as posted does not compile, there is no opening `xsl:template` start tag.

Comment: Closing the question: the issue is that the system I'm working in is changing the table on render. Apparently this system doesn't like nested table elements so it changes the code before load to what it THINKS it should be. Thank you everyone and sorry.

Comment: Get the first one instead of a loop perhaps.  Similar concept here https://stackoverflow.com/q/1498819/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the question: the issue is that the system I'm working in is changing the table on render. Apparently this system doesn't like nested table elements so it changes the code before load to what it THINKS it should be. Thank you everyone and sorry.